# xsltproc not supporting path cmdline argument?

Tags: linux, path, xml

I am using xsltrpoc for XSLT 1.0 stylesheets in linux box. I am using XSLT against my XML files. I need to import one file say base.xsl to my file say main.xsl. I realized to use the xsltproc --path feature to load base.xsl file so I don't have to worry about the exact location of my base file and I can directly import the file, something like:

main.xsl:

```
<xsl:import href="base.xsl"/>
```

and update xsltproc command to include the path something like:

```
xsltproc --xinclude --path "/path-to-base-dir/base.xsl" /path/to/main/xsl/file /path/to/my/xml/file
```

**Attempt:**

1. I tried to go through the logs using verbose mode, not able to track down the line saying given path is added. So is it completely ignored that parameter for my case?
2. It is not giving any error as well while including, that means atleast it has the support in general?
3. What can be the possible reasoning in this case?

Comment: Are you supposed to give the path to an XSL file with `--path` and not to a _directory_ containing XSL files?

Comment: @they I have passed the xsl file path

Comment: I know. I'm wondering whether you should be passing the path to the directory that contains that file, rather than the path to the file.

Comment: @they passing the directory seems to be working! any idea to support this?

Comment: proper syntax should be `xsltproc  --path "/path-to-base-dir" /path/to/main.xsl  /path/to/my/file.xml` . please note that `--path` is given a directory, not a file, so you can include many files. I can't check if `--xinclude` arg is mandatory.

Comment: @Archemar thanks, `--xinclude` I am adding for other purpose, you can ignore it for the current problem at hand